# Space getting added in IIS' URL rewrite rule when a new line exists in web.config

Tags: iis, url-rewriting

I have provided a PDF document containing sample URL rewrite rules to setup reverse proxy to our customers.
When they copy the config to their web.config, if the match URL overflows to the next line (a space gets added.
In the below example, when they copy the below configuration,

```
<rule name="ReverseProxyInboundRule1" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(xxyyzzURL|TestService|aabbccddeeffURL|
    testAbcdefURL/)(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny" trackAllCaptures="false" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="https://example.com/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

the URL rewrite will have a space before testAbcdefURL and doesn't match this URL

```
xxyyzzURL|TestService|aabbccddeeffURL| testAbcdefURL
```

Is there a way to fix the issue withour giving instruction to customer to remove the whitespaces?

Answer (score 0):

Through my test, it may be difficult to achieve because it is contrary to the setting of IIS to read the web.config file.

Mostly，few people add a new line in config file, especially the content in an attribute of a tag. So I have two ideas, you can refer to and make a decision according to your situation.

1. Use regex to match URL. I can’t exactly know the URL you want to match, so you can write it by yourself or use a regex generator online. To a certain extent, regex can shorten the match pattern unless the original URL is not long.
2. Edit the font and size on the pdf file so that the match url will not display a new line when the file is sent to your customers.
3. Suggest your customers use IIS GUI. It is easy to learn and use by refer to [Microsoft document.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/getting-started-with-iis/getting-started-with-the-iis-manager-in-iis-7-and-iis-8)

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I have solved it currently my created one inbound rule for each URL.

Comment: If your problem has been solved, please post the solution and mark it to help other who may have similar issues.